# Creating dynamic delivery date with shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to show an estimated delivery date below our 'add to cart'-button. Therefore I am using liquid and try to translate the english dates into german.

I also want to exclude Saturday & Sunday and instead use Monday (if the estimated delivery date is Sunday or Saturday).

This is what I came up with:

```
{% assign wday = "today" | date: "%a" %}
{% assign dtime = 4 | times: 86400 %}
{% assign dmonth = "today" | date: "%B" %}
{% assign dday = {{ wday | plus: dtime | date: "%a"}} %}
{% assign ddate = {{ "now" | date: '%s' | plus: dtime | date: "%-d %B" }} %}
{% assign gdate = "today" | date: "%a" %}

<!-- Translation Days -->
{% if dday == 'Mon' %}
    {% assign dday = "Montag" %}
{% elsif dday == 'Tue' %}
    {% assign dday = "Dienstag" %}
{% elsif dday == 'Wed' %}
    {% assign dday = "Mittwoch" %}
{% elsif dday == 'Thu' %}
    {% assign dday = "Donnerstag" %}
{% elsif dday == 'Fri' %}
    {% assign dday = "Freitag" %}
{% elsif dday == 'Sat' %}
    {% assign dday = "Samstag" %}
{% else %}
    {% assign dday = "Sonntag" %}
{% endif %}

<!-- Translation Months -->
{% if dmonth == 'January' %}
    {% assign dmonth = 'Januar' %}
{% endif %}

<div class="delivery-trust">
    <span class="check-icon"></span> Kostenloser DHL-Versand - <span class="delivery-date">Lieferung bis {{ dday }}, {{ dmonth }}</span>
</div>
```

dday works great already. Only weird thing is that you have to add 4 days dtime to get a 3-day increase in our current day.

I guess there is an easier way anyways but I have just started with liquid.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly {{ }} denotes output and {% %} denotes logic. You can't use output tags within logic tags.

So your assigns should be like this:

```
{% assign wday = "today" | date: "%a" %}
{% assign dtime = 4 | times: 86400 %}
{% assign dmonth = "today" | date: "%B" %}
{% assign dday = wday | date: "%s" | plus: dtime | date: "%a"  %}
{% assign ddate = "now" | date: '%s' | plus: dtime | date: "%-d %B" %}
{% assign gdate = "today" | date: "%a" %}
```

Other than that, your code should work fine.

To account for Saturdays and Sundays, you can simply check if dday is 'Sat' or 'Sun' and recalculate dtime if necessary. Like so:

```
{% assign wday = "today" | date: "%a" %}
{% assign dtime = 4 | times: 86400 %}
{% assign dmonth = "today" | date: "%B" %}
{% assign dday = wday | date: "%s" | plus: dtime | date: "%a"  %}

{% comment %}If dday is 'Sat' or 'Sun', recalculate to use Monday{% endcomment %}
{% if dday == 'Sat' %}
  {% assign dtime = dtime | plus: 172800 %}
{% elsif dday == 'Sun' %}
  {% assign dtime = dtime | plus: 86400 %}
{% endif %}
{% assign dday = wday | date: "%s" | plus: dtime | date: "%a"  %}

{% assign ddate = "now" | date: '%s' | plus: dtime | date: "%-d %B" %}
{% assign gdate = "today" | date: "%a" %}
```

As for having to add 4 days to get a 3 day increase, that is likely due to Shopify's caching. You can check this by outputting **{{ wday }}** beneath your **{% assign wday = "today" | date: "%a" %}** line. You may see that it shows the day yesterday instead of today.

It is better to use JavaScript for these sort of date related tasks as you can't rely on the accuracy of Shopify's cached date.